# When Does Marrionette ItemView onClose method get called?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to use the onClose event to clean up a view before removing it; although, for some reason it never gets called. I've tried calling region.empty, region.reset, showing a new view in the region and even destroying the region and the method just doesn't seem to get called. Is there a specific time that this event is raised?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which type of view you are using onClose and how you render that view? Is it Item||Collection||Composite/View which rendered using Region.show?

Comment: And please mention the version of Marionette?

Comment: I have missed the title, now it's clear regarding the view type.

Comment: Its a LayoutView, but from what I understand that inherits from ItemView

Comment: And which version of Marionette do you use?

Comment: I actually updated to the lastest a few weeks ago, which would explain onClose not working. Thanks for the help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From version 2.0 up to current version v2.2.0 of Marionette `ItemView`'s [`onClose`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v1.8.8/marionette.itemview.html#close--onclose-event) methods have changed its name to [`onDestroy`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.2.0/marionette.itemview.html#destroy--ondestroy-event).

There is a lot of other changes and enhancements. Please check [documentation](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.2.0/).